# Config files for system settings?

Tags: 16.04, unity, system-settings

It's easy to change system settings on 16.04 via the GUI. Do these settings correspond to a text file somewhere?

I run unity on both my laptop and desktop, and I'd like to sync keyboard shortcuts by soft linking to a configuration file in dropbox, for example this works quite nicely for bash: `ln -s ~/Dropbox/sync/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Yes, they do. But the question is too broad. There is a lot of different config files.

Comment: ^ that. Do you have specific settings in mind?

Comment: Particularly interested in the settings for keyboard shortcuts, especially Navigation (e.g. Move window to Workspace X)